# Create PDF documents from PDF templates from C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I have several PDF templates like lease and  rental agreements. Now a customer will select a template and a form will open for him to fill in required details-of course the form content will vary with template chosen.

Now I need to write the collected information to appropriate locations in the PDF template and create a new PDF document.

What is the best approach for this.

Thank you

Comment: Might want to check out [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/). It might have this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features/) for this.

- You can create your PDF templates visually with a PDF editor that is
  provided with the package, or you can create them programmatically if
  needed.
- You can show a PDF form (template) using a PDF Viewer control that is
  also provided.
- You can save the content of the PDF form as a new PDF file, and you
  can flatten the editable fields first if needed by setting the
  [Annotation attribute](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Amyuni_PDFCreator_IacObject/properties/IacObject_Properties.htm) to false in all the objects of all pages.

*Usual disclaimer applies*

Other libraries that you could use:

- PDFSharp (Open Source, it allows you to create PDF files, but it
  cannot display them)
- iText
  ([AGPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affero_General_Public_License),
  it allows you to create and process PDF files, but it cannot display
  them)